# Performance ramifications of serving FilePath rather than View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance

What are the performance ramifications if any of serving a FilePathResult rather than a view (If we have created server cached copies of a website using a headless browser)

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var url = Request.RawUrl.Replace("/", "_");
        var path = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PreloadPath"] + "\\" + url + ".html";
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
        {
            return new FilePathResult(path, "text/html");
        }
        else
        {
            return View("Index");
        }
    }
}
```

We are having to access the `AppSettings` every request now, use the File System to check if a file exists, and then serve that html file.

What costs are there compared with just

```
return View("Index");
```

Will the file access have any cost on the server? Or am I talking nonsense, and IIS would have to perform some similar action?

Note: Please suggest any other tags if I should add them

Answer (score -1):

Looking at the `FilePathResult`'s [source code](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/FilePathResult.cs) you can see that in the end it goes down to `WriteStreamAsText` of [HttpResponse](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/HttpResponse.cs,450e295218c430b2,references). It's obvious that there is no magic call to IIS for example to handle the file directly without any .Net code taking place.

Having said that I still expect this to be somewhat faster than running a view, which *possibly* needs interpretation and execution.

Comment: A view does not always require interpretation and execution.  Views are compiled into assemblies and then that code is executed.  Depending on the code that is in the view, it may or may not be faster than serving up a file.

Comment: Indeed you are right, I was a bit hasty while phrasing that. They still need to be executed and possibly compiled if the assembly if not there yet.

Comment: @casperOne however, since a view will generate HTML content too, in the average case, it will do some work before that and finally serve the content like a FilePathResult, so I expect this to be somewhat slower.